# using Awk how to convert the count displayed in text to a link to some webpage

Tags: awk, hyperlink

i am using awk to generate the report of error count. but the count displayed should now act as a link to a webpage.how to convert this text count to a link so that on clicking that number it takes me to some webpage???

My code is:

```
awk -F "," '{

      names[$4]=$4
      excpCount[$4]+=$5

   }END{
      n = asort(names,sorted)

      total=0
      for (i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
        jobName=sorted[i]
        if (jobName != "")
              printf("%43s       %9d\n", jobName,<html><body><a href="https://testlogger.atpco.org:8000/en-US/app/search/search?q=htstfmg01&earliest=-24h&latest=now#en-US/app/search/search?q=search%20ApplicationException%20host%3Dhtstfmg02&earliest=-24h&latest=now&sid=1448277655.90289&display.prefs.fieldFilter=">excpCount[jobName]</a></body></html>)
              total+=excpCount[jobName]
      }

      printf("%45s\n", "   ")
      printf("%43s %15s\n", "-----------------", "----------")
      printf("%43s %15d\n", "Total Errors", total)


}' ~/ode.$$.tmp
```

excpCount[jobName] gives the no. of times the exception occurs after generating report. can somebody help on this??

Comment: this is giving syntax error as html tags are not recognized inside awk I think

Comment: awk couldn't care less about html tags, they're just text like anything else. If you tell us what the syntax error is and what line awk is telling you it occurs on we can help you figure out it's meaning. More importantly - show sample input and expected output.

Answer (score 1):

You need to write your static HTML code as a part of the format String. Only the variable replacements are given as the successive arguments. So your line should be as follows:

```
printf("%43s <html><body><a href=\"http://yourLink.com\"> %9d </a></body></html>\n", jobName, excpCount[jobName])
```

Note that the quotes that are part of the link are escaped with a '\'. Also, replace the dummy link with your original link.

Comment: its output comes like this :

Comment: Exception Type         Count 
                          =================      ========== 
                       ApplicationException 
        18 

                       RemoteConnectFailure 
         2

Comment: the count is not coming in the same line..because of "<html><body><a href=\"http://yourLink.com\"> " in format string, the count gets printed in next line..how to avoid this ??

Comment: I couldn't understand your comments, but it seems like there is some server communication error. Can you elaborate your concern. And by the way, did you replace the dummy link (yourlink.com) with your desired link?